# How to project from Greek Grid to ETRS LAEA

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-9.3, proj, greece

How to make a project transformation between Greek Grid (EPSG:2100) to ETRS LAEA L52_M10?

I'm using ArcGis 9.3.1, but when I use the **project tool**, it don't have anything in "Geographic Transfornation" section.

How is it possible to make the transformation with proj4 library?

Comment: At 9.3.1, we probably didn't have a transformation from GGRS87 to ETRS89. The [EPSG registry] does list one between GGRS87 to WGS84: dx = -199.87, dy = 74.79, dz = 246.62. So you would have to combine two transformations or treat WGS84 and ETRS89 as identical and use the same parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using org2ogr library by using

`ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:2100 -t_srs EPSG:3035 outfile.shp infile.shp`